# TcpClient with timeout c#

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I'm using c# and TcpClient class with localhost, it work's fine in my computer but when computer is slow it doesn't work because "not properly respond after a period of time", I use Clumsy to simulate this "lag" in my computer, if the normal ping to localhost is 3ms with Clumsy it can be 50ms and then my application doesn't work.

My code:

```
public static MyClass connect()
{

        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
        tcpClient.SendTimeout = 10000;
        tcpClient.ReceiveTimeout = 10000;
        try
        {
            tcpClient.Connect("localhost", MY_PORT);
            NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            stream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TESTstring), 0, TESTstring.Length);
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            stream.Close();
            MyClass m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(response);

            return m;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            throw new TimeoutException();
        }
    }
```

I try with async connection but it crash when use GetStream because the socket is closed. (`tcp.Connected = false`)

```
 using (TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient())
 {
      IAsyncResult ar = tcp.BeginConnect("localhost", MY_PORT, null, null);
      System.Threading.WaitHandle wh = ar.AsyncWaitHandle;
      try
      {
         if (!ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), false))
         {
             tcp.Close();
             throw new TimeoutException();
         }
         MessageBox.Show("OK");

         NetworkStream stream = tcp.GetStream(); -> CRASH
```

Comment: So it's all working exactly as intended. What's your question?

Comment: @CodeCaster it works with a good computer but not with an old computer.

Comment: Expand on "old computer".  OS?  Spec?  NIC?

Comment: @JamesHarcourt I don't have the spec now it's an old computer with W10, but if you use Clumsy and check "lag" it doesn't work

Comment: @FCluster the point is that the spec of a computer is irrelevant, especially when you are dealing with networks.  Any number of things could cause the message to be delayed, or lost, or for the connection to be dropped altogether.  All of these things are well understood and discussed topics that you can research for yourself, but there is no specific 'problem' with anything in your code - you just need to learn how to handle these well-known problems.  Go and have a read

Comment: The test conditions etc. are too vague here.  Good luck with the other advice.

Comment: Voting to close: *but when computer is slow it doesn't work*: TCP/IP has been around since decades and is integrated in various of low-end devices; i cannot believe performance is the real issue here.

Comment: What about the receiving end, does it receive your `TESTstring`? Does it attempt to send data? One issue I see in your code is you're ignoring the return value of `stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);`. There's no reason to switch to async if you're only going to `WaitOne` immediately anyway, so I ignored that bit.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis it fails before, when I try to connect it spend a lot of time and crash. When I read it writes in my buffer and then I write from the buffer.